# draw radiation pattern of broadside antenna with number of five element

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

***i'm trying to draw broadside radiation pattern of antenna 
but i cannot any one could help me
[broadside radiation pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9KNE.png)`***

```
import math
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ArrayFac(angletheta):
    #try to use EQ=sin((N/2)*psi)/((N/2)*PSI)  
    n=5
    d=1
    psi=2*math.pi*d*math.cos(angletheta)
    num=math.sin((n/2)*psi)
    deu=(n/2)*psi
    arrafac=num/deu
    return abs(arrafac)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

for theta in range(181):
     ax.counter3d(0,theta,ArrayFac(theta))
     ax.legend()
ax.xlabel('x')
ax.ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
ax.show()
```

Comment: What's he error that you're getting?

Comment: i donnot have any error but the it didnot show any thing it's just empty schematic diagram

Comment: I haven't found any reference for counter3d in matplotlib. 
maybe is 'contour' what you need? [contour plots with matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#contour-plots)